# How to have working Admin LTE in yii2 basic application template

Tags: yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-rbac

I am using yii2 basic application template. How to configure, install and have working admin lte?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

1) Go to https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/releases and download last version.

2) Create folder bower in vendor path. And in bower create new folder admin-lte again.

3) Extract archive from first step to /vendor/bower/admin-lte.

4) Change your AppAsset (it is location in app/assets folder) and add this code:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
   public $sourcePath = '@bower/';
   public $css = ['admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.css'];
   public $js = ['admin-lte/dist/js/AdminLTE/app.js'];
   public $depends = [
       'yii\web\YiiAsset',
       'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
       'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
   ];
}
```

**Method 2**

To install AdminLTE v2 run:

```
php composer.phar require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "2.*"
```

To install AdminLTE v1 run:

```
php composer.phar require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "1.*"
```

Add below lines in your `config/web.php` inside the components array. It will diplay example views. Change the path accordingly

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@app/views' => '@vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app'
            ],
         ], 
    ],
],
```